# chef client install issue

Tags: chef-infra

I downloaded `chef-12.0.3-1.x86_64.rpm`

I see that that contents will be created under /opt/chef. But I don't have write permissions on /opt

when I perform

```
rpm -ivh chef-12.0.3-1.x86_64.rpm
```

I get permission denied error on /opt and /var

Is there a way to install this onto a different folder without root privileges.

Answer (score 2):

No, like most RPM packages Chef is not relocatable. You'll have to build your own packages with a different path or do the install from scratch. Most Chef recipes also expect to run as root, so I'm not sure what you plan to do with it.